# Google Sheets group by with strings?

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheet (a list of Google Shared Drives and their members output from GAM) that looks like the following, with one line per emailAddress, but the first three columns are identical for each shared drive:

| id | name | createdTime | emailAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drive A | 2024-01-09T17:15:21-08:00 | `a@example.org` |
| 1 | Drive A | 2024-01-09T17:15:21-08:00 | `b@example.org` |
| 1 | Drive A | 2024-01-09T17:15:21-08:00 | `d@example.org` |
| 1 | Drive A | 2024-01-09T17:15:21-08:00 | `g@example.org` |
| 2 | Drive B | 2021-03-11T16:17:33-08:00 | `a@example.org` |
| 2 | Drive B | 2021-03-11T16:17:33-08:00 | `c@example.org` |
| 3 | Drive C | 2018-12-27T08:41:39-08:00 | `j@example.org` |
| 3 | Drive C | 2018-12-27T08:41:39-08:00 | `k@example.org` |
| 3 | Drive C | 2018-12-27T08:41:39-08:00 | `l@example.org` |

I want to transform it to look like the following, with one line per shared drive:

| id | name | createdTime | emailAddresses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Drive A | 2024-01-09T17:15:21-08:00 | `a@example.org,b@example.org,d@example.org,g@example.org` |
| 2 | Drive B | 2021-03-11T16:17:33-08:00 | `a@example.org,c@example.org` |
| 3 | Drive C | 2018-12-27T08:41:39-08:00 | `j@example.org,k@example.org,l@example.org` |

See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V3VL67aQfCk1H6nsqoavESVKiNMtqml3qx2sao87iYY/edit?usp=sharing) for an example sheet with source and desired result in it.

If I was in something like BigQuery, I'd probably just accomplish this with `GROUP BY` and `ARRRAY_AGG` and `UNNEST`, but I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing in Sheets.

Comment: The reason the formatting of the emailAddress column is funky is because the automated checker for improperly formatted code wouldn't let that column through unless I wrapped the email addresses in code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula-

```
=LET(
x,UNIQUE('Source data'!A2:C),
y,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER('Source data'!D2:D,'Source data'!A2:A=INDEX(z,1),'Source data'!B2:B=INDEX(z,2),'Source data'!C2:C=INDEX(z,3))))),
HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]